# Envoy "http_connection_manager" setup issue

Tags: reverse-proxy, envoyproxy

I am new to the Envoy proxy. I am trying to understand the filters basic config for "**http_connection_manager**"

I have this code :

```
filter_chains:
    - filters:
        - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
            codec_type: auto
            stat_prefix: ingress_http
```

I need help in understanding what is the meeting of :

1. **name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager** --- ( I think it is an inbuild HTTP filter of some kind)
2. **"@type":type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager**   --- (I have no idea, what is this )

I tried to understand it from official docs and also read some medium posts, some youtube videos, but still, I have not able to decode the meaning of these lines.

If somebody has an answer, I will be grateful. even any resource, post or video link, or any kind of info is also appreciated, please share those if possible. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `name` field indicates the common name of the extension you want to turn on.  They typically have enough information in the name to give you a little bit of a handle on what they do and where in the toolchain they are.

   - `envoy` means this is packaged straight with envoy.  Not a 3rd party extension
   - `filters` means this is a filter extension.  Envoy does also support other types of [extensions](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/config), though filters is probably the most common.
   - `network` means this is a network filter.  This operates at the TCP level.  You'll also commonly see `http` here for filters that operate on HTTP requests.
   - `http_connection_manager` the specific filter.  This is the HTTP connection manager, which does basically what it says: handles all the HTTP connections.  Without this you don't get HTTP route handling, header manipulation, virtual hosts, etc. [full features](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/http_conn_man#config-http-conn-man)
2. The `type` is indicating the exact spec of the protobuf config that will be sent to the filter to initialize it and trigger behavior.  It's a bit opaque, just know that each filter has a v2 and a v3 set of configuration options available.  For any given filter, the envoy docs do link to their typed config.  E.g. [the kafka broker page](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/kafka_broker/v3/kafka_broker.proto#extensions-filters-network-kafka-broker-v3-kafkabroker) and [the direct proto definition](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/b4b82411487d66290da72948b3090ad2ed605c96/api/envoy/extensions/filters/network/kafka_broker/v3/kafka_broker.proto#L17)

Comment: also, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473416/envoy-configuration-possible-values-of-type-keys

Comment: Thanks a lot. this answer really helped me a lot to understand. I do not have enough points to upvote your answer, or I will do that.

Comment: No worries at all, glad to be helpful.  Even without enough points though, you can still accept my answer as the one that solved your problem by clicking the green arrow.  [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: did it, accepted as an answer. i did not know that.

Comment: did you know any resources to read what this '@type' is? I now understand fully what the 'name' field indicates, but still '@type' is not clear.

Comment: the `@type` is the specifier for the configuration payload.  E.g. the `http_connection_manager` has a different configuration type than the `kafka_broker`.  For your example above, it's saying that the config that follows is going to be a protobuf message with [these](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/b4b82411487d66290da72948b3090ad2ed605c96/api/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#L3) fields